# OSX Mavericks + EPD Canopy + mpi4py

Tags: mpi, enthought

having issues with the latest version of OSX and Canopy.  I need mpi4py and have never had a problem compiling it with previous operating systems.  With 10.9 however, they seem to have moved from gcc to clang and I can't get mpi4py compiled for the life of me.  It compiles fine in anaconda, but not with Canopy.  Has anyone had any luck with this?

Comment: Apple has abandoned GCC for long time in favour of clang and has been providing llvm-gcc only for transitional purposes. Unless your code requires the llvm-gcc specific _blocks_ (Apple's take on lambda functions), you'd be better off compiling a recent GCC from source.

Answer (score 1):

(Enthought Support here)

The latest version of XCode (version 5) that was released with OS X 10.9 Mavericks has removed support for `gcc`, such that `gcc` is no longer actually the GNU Compiler Collection, but is symlinked to the `clang` compiler.

Users still hoping to access a C compiler for their projects, such as in building C-extensions using Cython, should generally not run into any problems in using the symlinked `gcc` (or directly using `clang`), as `clang` uses the same LLVM backend and libraries as Apple's previous `gcc` compiler.

However, if you are building a C++ library (via `clang++`) that you will later link with a Python extension, or if you are building a Python extension that uses a C++ library, you need to use the older libraries (libstdc++, and not the `clang++` default of libc++) via these compiler/linker flags: `-stlib=libstdc++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.6`

As it may be preferable for some users, it is still possible to install and use Xcode 4.6.3 on an OSX 10.9, but note that these developer tools do not include the 10.9 SDK.

This information can also be found in our Knowledge Base: https://support.enthought.com/entries/26184115-GCC-Clang-and-Cython-in-OS-X-10-9-Mavericks